# Installation failed - In order to continue installing, you need to be an owner

Tags: macos, user-account, monterey, apfs, migration

I ran into an interesting and very troubling error when trying to install system updates in macOS 12.4:

[image: example]

It seems as though the root of this problem happened during the setup phase of this new Apple Silicon system. When performing the system migration from an old system to the new, I stopped `Migration Assistant` to change from wi-fi to ethernet so that the transfer would be a bit quicker. It didn't allow me to change without actually restarting the migration process and so it initially had, apparently, created two users at some point, but these were not completed users that were migrated during the system setup. Instead another users was created as a temporary user in order to get back into the `Migration Assistant`.

After then performing the (very large and many hour) migration the system started working and has been working seemingly fine, except when I try to perform system updates.

It turns out that this has to do with APFS ownership of the volume (FileVault is not enabled) and the initial user that was created is shown as the owner, but the REAL owner of the system is not being shown as the owner of the APFS volume.

Everything I've dug into so far seems to want to work with FileVault ownership, but nothing seems to really pertain to changing / adding APFS volume owners. The way in which the APFS ownership is displayed (`sudo diskutil apfs listUsers /`) seems to indicate from this tree view that there can be multiple owners of a volume. I saw some remarks that seemed to lead to commands involving `sudo fdesetup changerecovery ...` and modification of the token via `sudo dscl . -append /Users/<USERNAME> AuthenticationAuthority ";DisabledTags;SecureToken"` , etc... but none of these seem to do the trick or work quite right.

What's the right way to add users to the ownership of an APFS volume in Monterey?

Comment: idk how to do this, but even before APFS it was simpler to wipe the Mac & start over than to merge a 'late' migration. It really needs to be done as part of the initial setup.

Comment: Not going to start over, no. Too much wear on the SSD and too much time for migrating over 6tb of data.

Comment: You will probably spend more time trying to fix this than redoing the migration.

Comment: "too much wear"?

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this same error, never seen it before! Learn something new every day.

So, apparently, from what I've read, the FIRST account created on the computer is the 'owner', and any new accounts created BY THAT FIRST ACCOUNT can also be 'owners'.  That is the only answer I've found so far.

I had a brand new Ventura OS iMac, I created a new user "Test", then used data migration app to import from Time Machine backup disk. I had 2 user accounts imported via the data migration app into the new system, and one became an 'owner' as listed by the  terminal command:
sudo diskutil apfs listUsers /

But for some reason, the other imported user did NOT become an owner, and thus got this error message when attempting to install a macOS update. Luckily, I was able to use the "Test" user account to install the macOS update.

So, during a data migration, it's a little unclear as to why some accounts get ownership while others do not.

Reading on this Apple page explained it a little, but not how to manually make a non-owner into an owner, but only how to add a new user account from an existing 'owner', and that would get the rights of ownership.

See Apple page:

https://support.apple.com/en-om/guide/deployment/dep24dbdcf9e/web

in particular this bit of text:
" Instead, volume ownership can loosely be defined as the user who first claimed a Mac by configuring it for their own use, along with any additional users. You must be a volume owner to make changes to the startup security policy for a specific install of macOS, authorize the installation of macOS software updates and upgrades, initiate an Erase All Content and Settings, and more. The startup security policy defines the restrictions around which versions of macOS can boot, as well as how and if third-party kernel extensions can be loaded or managed."

Oh, and for what it's worth, in the past, if anything ever interrupted a data migration, I would almost always find it better to erase the disk and start over from scratch, even if it's massive amount of data and takes a long time, also, I wouldn't work about 'too much wear' as the SSD disks are going to be used WAY more on a daily basis, and cause WAY MORE wear of SSD than any data migration would, so, I would presume it would NOT cause any noticeable wear even to re-migrate multiple TB of data.

Cheers,
Daniel